# Wii U Gamepad syncing symbols don't match

Tags: wii-u

This is my situation on the WII U gamepad:

I press the sync button and the tv shows the code for me to enter into the WII U Gamepad so that it connects.

The code on my tv does not match the symbols on my Gamepad, for some reason there is a picture of a clover with 4 curves instead of 3 curves

What do I do? there is no button of a 4 curved sided clover.

Answer (score 2):

Fully charge your WiiU Gamepad.
Press the sync button on the WiiU **twice**.
Make sure you press the sync buton on the back of the Gamepad as well. (You will need a stylus to do this.)

Use the touch screen to enter the code that appears on the TV screen by pressing the squares with the spade, diamond, heart and clover.

[image: From Nintendo support website]

The symbols should appear as above (with possibly a different code on the TV screen.)

If the symbols do not show up correctly, try resetting and trying again.
If there is any other problems syncing, you may need to turn off any nearby wireless devices.

For any other queries check [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1996/p/431/c/621/session/L3RpbWUvMTQzMjU3NDAzNi9zaWQvZ3cxbXBlbm0%3D).

If that still does not work, you may need to send it in for [repairs](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/repair/repair_redirect.jsp?sys=wiiu&lang=en&sym=GPADNOSYNC).

Comment: How does one reset the gamepad?

Comment: I meant just turn off both the Gamepad and the WiiU and then wait 5-10 mins then turn them back on again.